# Rails 3 Postgres uses single field index for query, but shouldn't it use the compound index?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, indexing

So `User` has many `:orders`, which works like you expect. I also have a `valid` scope on order that should filter by ensuring the orders are in a set of whitelisted states (not canceled orders, for instance)

I've declared some indices on the orders table, and my `schema.rb` looks like:

```
add_index "orders", ["state"], :name => "index_orders_on_state"
add_index "orders", ["user_id", "state"], :name => "index_orders_on_user_id_and_state"
add_index "orders", ["user_id"], :name => "index_orders_on_user_id"
```

When I run `puts user.orders.valid.explain` I get this:

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"
             WHERE "orders"."user_id" = 1 AND 
                   "orders"."state" IN ('pending', 'packed', 'shipped', 'in_transit', 'delivered', 'return_pending', 'returned')
      QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on orders  (cost=4.60..154.88 rows=40 width=3323)
   Recheck Cond: (user_id = 1)
   Filter: ((state)::text = ANY ('{pending,packed,shipped,in_transit,delivered,return_pending,returned}'::text[]))
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_orders_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..4.59 rows=44 width=0)
         Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
```

So given that I am searching on `user_id` and `state`, and a have a compound index for both those fields, why is it not using the `index_orders_on_user_id_and_state` index?  Or am I just reading this explain output wrong?

Is it doing two passes? One to find orders by `user_id`, and then another pass to check for `state`?

I need to run queries like this a lot, on a lot of records at once. So any way to keep it speedy is a very good thing.

Comment: About what portion of your rows have those `state` values? Sometimes the table stats suggest that a scan will be cheaper than using an index. Indexes give the query optimizer extra options, they don't force the optimizer to make any particular choices.

Comment: `state` can be one of 8 or 9 values, so perhaps it's just deciding that it doesn't need the more specific index.  I guess the choice to use an index or not is more nuanced than I thought it to be.

Comment: I mean if, say, 90% of your rows have a `state` of `'pending'`, ... `'returned'` (i.e. the ones you're looking for) then consulting the index might be pointless. Query optimization is a bit of a black art, it depends on the queries, the indexes, **and** the contents of the table. Also, indexing low cardinality columns generally isn't that useful and you `state` might fall in the low cardinality category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database system may decide not to use indexes. For example with Mysql, if the table data is small, it may decide to do a full table scan. You can try putting several million of records and execute the query again to see how the plan change.

Comment: So in short, the answer is "because Postgres doesn't want to" in this case? But the indexes do look to be setup to use the more specific index if necessary right?

Comment: I don't know very well about how postgres operates. But it is very likely that Postgres will use the more specific index if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good explanation of the internal usage of postgres indexes is here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes

the relevant part is

> There are many reasons why the Postgres planner may choose to not use
>   an index. Most of the time, the planner chooses correctly, even if it
>   isn’t obvious why. It’s okay if the same query uses an index scan on
>   some occasions but not others. The number of rows retrieved from the
>   table may vary based on the particular constant values the query
>   retrieves. So, for example, it might be correct for the query planner
>   to use an index for the query select * from foo where bar = 1, and yet
>   not use one for the query select * from foo where bar = 2, if there
>   happened to be far more rows with “bar” values of 2. When this
>   happens, a sequential scan is actually most likely much faster than an
>   index scan, so the query planner has in fact correctly judged that the
>   cost of performing the query that way is lower.